# Which cards does Heimdall move?

Tags: marvel-snap

Heimdall is a card with the following effect. *On Reveal: Move your other cards one location to the left.*

Assuming that all of my locations are full except for a location that has space for one card, which card on its left will move there? Will it be the first one, the last one, or is it chosen randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on personal experience as well as answers from other players on the official game Discord server, it seems that the **first** card in the location will be the one that moves.